# Zend Form class not found error

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I am getting this error what should I do ?

```
Fatal error: Class 'forms_AuthForm' not found in C:\dev\workspaces\
adxweb\application\adxsearch\modules\account\controllers\
AuthController.php on line 26
```

I have one `AuthForm.php` in `forms` folder and `Authcontroller.php` in `controllers` folder, and `auth.phtml` in `scripts` folder.

Thanks 
kiran

Comment: Please provide the exact location of the forms directory. Zend apparently hasn't been informed about the whereabouts of your forms and is looking in the wrong location.

Comment: Also, consider renaming the class to `Form_AuthForm`. The `Form` part gets interpreted as "look in the `forms` directory".

Comment: the forms directory is modules/account/forms.. and in AuthForm.php its will be like this   class forms_AuthForm extends Zend_Form

Comment: I think @mingos' point is that the standard module autoloader looks for a class named `Form_XXX` in the file `application/forms/XXX.php` (assuming a blank appnamespace).

Answer (score 1):

The default path for forms in ZF projects is `APPLICATION_PATH`/forms, like this:

```
-- application
    -- forms
        AuthForm.php
    -- models
    -- modules
        -- account
            -- controllers
                AuthController.php
            -- views
                -- helpers
                -- scripts
                    -- auth
                        index.phtml
                        ...
```

If you wish to place your forms elsewhere, you will need to tell Zend where that location is (it can be done in the bootstrap or, I think, in application.ini).

Also, make sure your classes are named appropriately, as they reflect the paths to the files they're contained in. The names are case sensitive.

[EDIT]

Read this article: http://bsagols.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/zend_loader_autoloader-stand-alone-and-modular-approaches/ - it describes what you appear to be after (modular approach, with per-module forms).

This is the long way around though. The way I'd solve it is moving your forms to `application/forms`. You can create module-specific folders there, like this:

```
--application
    -- forms
        -- Auth
            Auth.php
```

You form class name would then be `Namespace_Form_Auth_Auth`, where `Namespace` is your application namespace. This approach requires no modifications to the bootstrap or application.ini.

Comment: @mingos..thanks and what should write the code in bootstrap or application.ini file?

Answer (score 1):

Try `$form = new Application_Form_AuthForm()` instead of `$form = new forms_AuthForm()` in your controller file `AuthController.php`

and make sure that you have `class Application_Form_AuthForm extends Zend_Form` in your `forms/authform.php`.

If you want to remove the namespace `Application` then in your `application.ini` file set `appnamespace = "Application"` to `appnamespace =`

Comment: @kiran can you add your directory structure to question and the code in `controller file` and `form` file

Answer (score 1):

If you use modular directory structure:

```
// application/modules/modulename/forms/Name.php
class Modulename_Form_Name extends Zend_Form {
   public function init() {
     $this->addElements(array(/** */));
   }
}
```

Then no additional setup is needed,
except `resources.modules[]=` in `application.ini` and a module bootstrap for `modulename` module.