# Unable to access zend views from controller file

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

In the controler i have this

```
public function loginAction()
{
 $form = new forms_AuthForm();
 $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

In the Authform.php i have login details..

```
class forms_AuthForm extends Zend_Form
{
   public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($options);
        $this->setName('login');

 $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username','username');
        $username->setLabel('Username: *')
                  ->setRequired(true);

 $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('password','password');
        $password->setLabel('Password: *')
                  ->setRequired(true);

 $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit','submit');
        $submit->setLabel('Login');

        $this->addElements(array($username, $password,
            $submit));
```

In the login.phtml i have given

```
echo $this->form;
```

form design is not viewed, instead displaying blank page. what could be the issue ?

I am able to print the form content in the controller file, but when I assign the form view as

```
$this->view->form = $form
```

and trying to display the form design in login.phtml file, form design is not visible.

Comment: Too little info to deduce anything. Maybe a path problem?

Comment: @mingos.. see the edited text..

Comment: @kiran can you post the source code of AuthForm.php?

Comment: @emaillenin ..Check the edited code in AuthForm.php

Comment: in your login.phtml, other than echo $this->form, can try echoing something else and see if you get the output?

Comment: *duplicate* of [Zend Form class not found error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115456/zend-form-class-not-found-error). Please read the answer to your previous question. It is *exactly* the same problem.

Comment: yes i am getting output..and one more thing is already some images are calling from login.phtml..they are also displaying..only the thing is form..

Comment: @Aron..yes its duplicate of zendfrom class not found error..but no one solved my prob..if u want i always ready to take help from u..i am expecting some thing new from others..ok thanks for remaind me for its a duplicate..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some decorators to your Authform.php:

```
    $this->setDecorators(array(
        'FormElements',
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dl', 'class' => 'zend_form')),
        array('Description', array('placement' => 'prepend')),
        'Form'
    ));
```

If I remove this from my form (which looks identical to yours bar the decorators) my form doesn't display, but the other items on the page are displayed, just no form.